# Java: Custom client can't read font

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, fonts

I have an enterprise application client and I want a custom font.

Exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
at java.awt.Font.createFont0(Font.java:1000)
at java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:877)
at de.fh_dortmund.inf.cw.surstwalat.client.user.view.LoginPanel.<init>(LoginPanel.java:68)
```

Code:

```
public void loaderFonts() {
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        try {
//            ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("resources/fonts/closeandopen.ttf")));

            InputStream stream = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/resources/fonts/closeandopen.ttf");
            Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, stream).deriveFont(16f);
            ge.registerFont(font);
        } catch (IOException | FontFormatException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
//        } finally {
//            String[] fontnames = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
//            for (String fontname : fontnames) {
//                System.out.println(fontname);
//            }
        }
```

I tried a few things, but found no solution.

- different fonts
- different ways to see comments
- paths
- etc

maybe some ideas?

Comment: Any `Caused by:` lines in the stack trace? Try `e.getCause()` in the `catch` block.

Comment: To expand on the comment that @JozefChocholacek made - try an `e.printStackTrace();` to make sure you're seeing everything.